# Create IISRewrite rule for non www to www for toplevel domain only

Tags: iis, umbraco, umbraco7, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to redirect my non-www users to the www version. But only for our topdomain.

This is my current rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect Non WWW" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)domainname\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.{C:1}/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
```

This works, but a bit too well unfortunately. We also have a few subdomains:  https://subdomain.domainname.com . The rule also redirects these, as they don't contain www.

How can I make my rewrite rule only redirect visitors to https://domainname.com/ and not our subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <rule name="Redirect Non WWW" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domainname\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.{C:1}/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
```